# Regex ignore pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex, pattern-matching

I have a text with some annotation-marks. brackets '(' and ')' or '[' and ']' are used to determine what is part of the annotation (it´s like in a normal text, like this sentence). i want to perform a regex on it to search something in the input, but... it should ignore all annotations.

the problems are:

- they can appear at any place (i don´t know where and how many)
- i can not strip them easily (performing a replace-regex to kill all appearences), because i need to know the indexes and length after performing my search-regex in the original text
- it has to be as fast as possible on a HUGE input-text

the annotations can not be nested, something like "123 (Hello (World))" will not appear. if the annotation-brackets are part of a string (in quotes), they are part of the text and therefore no annotation.

here is an example:

```
Input Text: "Hello, my (real) name is John. I worked in England (near London) on a real german restaurant.".

Search Regex: "my.*?real"

Output: "my (real) name is John. I worked in England (near London) on a real" (index=7, length=67)
```

what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: i think you can try to replace all annotations on some exotic placeholder like # having equal lenght with annotations and after that searh your text. example: (real) replace on ######

Comment: i dont know where they are in the input, how many and what is between the brackets. i just know "everything in brackets has to be ignored. for example the pattern "ac" has to match on the input "a(b)c"

Comment: you can use regex for search annotations and after that replace it on placeholder

Comment: Why to use search? It's easier with `Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "")` this method will replace all the strings that match the _pattern_ in the _input_ to empty string.

Comment: @Dzienny: i already said, i need the indexes and length of the founds. this information will be lost, if i just replace all matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if RegEx is not your friend in this situation. Especially since you want the fastest possible algorithm, maybe you should implement this as a state machine.

In essence, rip through the string one character at a time and keep a stack of matching annotation delimiters. As long as you're not inside an annotation, also watch for the string you are trying to match.

Clarifying questions: Are you able to assume that the text you're searching for is a fixed literal? Do you care about quantity of whitespace? I'm asking because, once you've eliminated the "annotation" issue, you may not need all the power of RegExes to do the rest of the search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
my.*?real(?![^(\[]*[\)\]])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this following code it may be us

```
  public string output { get; set; }

  string input="Hello, my [FirstName] name is John. I worked in England [nearLondon] on a real german restaurant.".
  static readonly Regex re = new Regex(@"\{([^\}]+)\}", RegexOptions.Compiled);

  StringDictionary fields = new StringDictionary();
  fields.Add("FirstName", yourname);
  fields.Add("nearLondon", yournearLondon);

  output = re.Replace(input, delegate(Match match)
        {
            return fields[match.Groups[1].Value];
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string source =
            @"Hello, my (real) name is John. I worked in England (near London) on a real  german restaurant.";

        Regex regex=new Regex(@"\(.*?\)");

        MatchCollection matchCollection= regex.Matches(source);

        foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            source = source.Replace(match.Groups[0].Value, GetPlaceholderString(match.Groups[0].Length));
        }
        MessageBox.Show(source);
```

where `GetPlaceholderString` making plactholder string with needed length.

After that you can search you word ignore and all anotations